# Pass an array of protocol conforming objects to function

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I would like to write a function that takes an array of objects conforming to a given protocol. I wrote the following Playground code:

```
protocol Request {}

struct RequestA: Request {}
struct RequestB: Request {}

func execute<T: Request>(requests: [T]) {}

let requests: [Request] = [RequestA(), RequestB()]

execute(requests: requests)
```

However, on the last line I receive this error: "Value of protocol type 'Request' cannot conform to 'Request'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols".

I believe that this error is happening because the function expects an array of objects conforming to the protocol, not an array of the protocols, but I am lost on how to do this another way.

Can someone help sort this out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just don't need the generic type `T`. Change your function to this `func execute(requests: [Request]) {}`

Comment: Do you really need to mix different type of objects in the same collection? Note that using a protocol as the element type only the properties required by the protocol will be accessible inside that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said you want to have `func execute(requests: [Request]) {}` in this case.

The reasoning is that `func execute<T: Request>(requests: [T]) {}` as a generic function is saying you want a concrete known type `T` that conforms to the `Request` protocol.

The change to `[Request]` from `[T]` lets you have an array of any type that conforms to `Request` instead of an array of one type that conforms.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I was under the impression that I must use generics. Could you maybe give an example on where it would be impossible to avoid having to use generics? I can think of the protocol having an associated type maybe.

Comment: Ya if there is an associated type or Self requirements (also known as a PAT) then you have to use genetics. So one example is if you wanted to take a StringProtocol. It is a PAT so you would need to constrain it the way you have which would then make the implementation take an Array or String or Substring but you couldn’t mix them together in the array. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

```swift
func execute(requests: [Request]) {}
```